# how to insert listview subitems to database in c#

Tags: c#, database, listview, visual-studio-2013, listviewitem

I am passing strings that were added to the listview to the database to be stored and,
This error appears when the code is running:

> An unhandled exception of type `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException` occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I would like to know where I went wrong.
Here is the code:

```
for (int y = 0; y < LVProgram.Items.Count; y++)
{
     conn.Open();
     string qq2 = @"insert into mydb.clientProgram(clientStrengthTrain) 
                 values('" + LVProgram.Items[y].SubItems[0].Text + "','" + 
                 LVProgram.Items[y].SubItems[1].Text + "','" + 
                 LVProgram.Items[y].SubItems[2].Text + "','" + 
                 LVProgram.Items[y].SubItems[3].Text + "','" + 
                 LVProgram.Items[y].SubItems[4].Text + "','" + 
                 LVProgram.Items[y].SubItems[5].Text + "');";
     MySqlCommand myCommand33 = new MySqlCommand(qq2, conn);
     myReader = myCommand33.ExecuteReader();
     conn.Close();
 }
```

Comment: _Additional information: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1_ its very clear, is there number of columns same as you put values into insert query?

Comment: oh yes, right. however, i need all the subitems in one column in the database called "clientStrengthTrain"...so i thought it adds all of it in one column

Answer (score 0):

add this.          in every start in your values. for example:

+this.LVProgram.Items[y].SubItems[0].Text+